# Cell Address Manipulation

Tags: excel, vba

[image: ex21]

I have this information auto-populating in a macro.  The cell address returns the correct `$E$6`.

[![ex22][2]][2]

However, I need the `$E$6` to print `A3` along with the other 95 positions.  ie.   c.address `$G$8` = `C5`

Someone please tell me this type of conversion is possible.  I haven't been able to find much of anything browsing the internet for the last couple hours.

```
Sub generateRR()
Dim rField As Range
Dim r2Field As Range
Dim r3Field As Range
Dim r4Field As Range
Dim idCell As Range
Dim r1WS As Worksheet
Dim rrWS As Worksheet
Dim r2WS As Worksheet
Dim r3WS As Worksheet
Dim r4WS As Worksheet

Set r1WS = Worksheets("RACK 1")
Set r2WS = Worksheets("RACK 2")
Set r3WS = Worksheets("RACK 3")
Set r4WS = Worksheets("RACK 4")
Set rField = r1WS.Range("C6:N13")
Set r2Field = r2WS.Range("C6:N13")
Set r3Field = r3WS.Range("C6:N13")
Set r4Field = r4WS.Range("C6:N13")
Set rrWS = Worksheets("Reruns To Pull")

For Each idCell In rField

  If idCell.Interior.color = RGB(204, 204, 255) Then
        With rrWS.Range("A1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Value = idCell.Value
            idCell.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            rrWS.Range("B1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = idCell.Address
        End With
  
    ElseIf idCell.Interior.color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then
        With rrWS.Range("A1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Value = idCell.Value
            idCell.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            rrWS.Range("B1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = idCell.Address
        End With
    
    ElseIf idCell.Interior.color = RGB(255, 153, 204) Then
        With rrWS.Range("A1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Value = idCell.Value
            idCell.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            rrWS.Range("B1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = idCell.Address
        End With
    
    ElseIf idCell.Interior.color = RGB(204, 255, 255) Then
       With rrWS.Range("A1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Value = idCell.Value
            idCell.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            rrWS.Range("B1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = idCell.Address
        End With
    
    End If
    
Next idCell

rrWS.Columns.AutoFit

For Each idCell In r2Field

If idCell.Interior.color = RGB(204, 204, 255) Then
        With rrWS.Range("D1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            ' Paste values.
            .Value = idCell.Value
            ' Paste formats.
            idCell.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
  
    ElseIf idCell.Interior.color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then
        With rrWS.Range("D1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            ' Paste values.
            .Value = idCell.Value
            ' Paste formats.
            idCell.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    
    ElseIf idCell.Interior.color = RGB(255, 153, 204) Then
        With rrWS.Range("D1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            ' Paste values.
            .Value = idCell.Value
            ' Paste formats.
            idCell.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    
    ElseIf idCell.Interior.color = RGB(204, 255, 255) Then
       With rrWS.Range("D1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            ' Paste values.
            .Value = idCell.Value
            ' Paste formats.
            idCell.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    
    End If
    
Next idCell

rrWS.Columns.AutoFit

For Each idCell In r3Field

If idCell.Interior.color = RGB(204, 204, 255) Then
        With rrWS.Range("G1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            ' Paste values.
            .Value = idCell.Value
            ' Paste formats.
            idCell.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
  
    ElseIf idCell.Interior.color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then
        With rrWS.Range("G1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            ' Paste values.
            .Value = idCell.Value
            ' Paste formats.
            idCell.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    
    ElseIf idCell.Interior.color = RGB(255, 153, 204) Then
        With rrWS.Range("G1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            ' Paste values.
            .Value = idCell.Value
            ' Paste formats.
            idCell.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    
    ElseIf idCell.Interior.color = RGB(204, 255, 255) Then
       With rrWS.Range("G1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            ' Paste values.
            .Value = idCell.Value
            ' Paste formats.
            idCell.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    
    End If
    
Next idCell

rrWS.Columns.AutoFit


For Each idCell In r4Field

If idCell.Interior.color = RGB(204, 204, 255) Then
        With rrWS.Range("J1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            ' Paste values.
            .Value = idCell.Value
            ' Paste formats.
            idCell.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
  
    ElseIf idCell.Interior.color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then
        With rrWS.Range("J1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            ' Paste values.
            .Value = idCell.Value
            ' Paste formats.
            idCell.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    
    ElseIf idCell.Interior.color = RGB(255, 153, 204) Then
        With rrWS.Range("J1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            ' Paste values.
            .Value = idCell.Value
            ' Paste formats.
            idCell.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    
    ElseIf idCell.Interior.color = RGB(204, 255, 255) Then
       With rrWS.Range("J1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            ' Paste values.
            .Value = idCell.Value
            ' Paste formats.
            idCell.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    
    End If
    
Next idCell

rrWS.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

There's a few more loops going on after, but it's all essentially the same.

Comment: seems doable. you are talking about offsetting the data, correct?

Comment: pop your code into your question and I will have a look

Comment: Warning, it's pretty cluttered.

Comment: Since I'm learning still, I figured this is a perfect opportunity for me to practice condensing if it's able to be finished.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: My answer didn't work out in the end deLa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good amount of duplicated/similar code which can mostly be factored out:

```vb
Sub generateRR()

    Dim idCell As Range, rrWS As Worksheet, n As Long, arrColors, rngDest As Range
    
    Set rrWS = Worksheets("Reruns To Pull")
    
    arrColors = Array(RGB(204, 204, 255), RGB(255, 153, 0), _
                      RGB(255, 153, 204), RGB(204, 255, 255), vbRed)
    
    For n = 1 To 4
        
        'get the firt empty row for this rack listing
        Set rngDest = rrWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A"). _
                         Offset(0, (n - 1) * 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        
        For Each idCell In Worksheets("RACK " & n).Range("C6:N13").Cells
            'is the cell color one of the listed values in arrColors?
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(idCell.Interior.Color, arrColors, 0)) Then
                
                'got a match - copy value and fill color
                rngDest.Value = idCell.Value
                rngDest.Interior.Color = idCell.Interior.Color
                'get the rack location - cell parent is the worksheet object
                rngDest.Offset(0, 1).Value = idCell.Parent.Cells(idCell.Row, "B").Value & _
                                            idCell.Parent.Cells(5, idCell.Column).Value
                
                Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0) 'next listing row for this rack
            End If
        Next idCell
        
    Next n
  
    rrWS.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Loop over rField is different from other loops. The other loops have its own output destination each.

Comment: `Offset(0, (n - 1) * 3)` takes care of that when `rngDest` is set...

Comment: Loop over rField is still different from other loops.

Comment: I agree but I'm guessing that's because the OP's code is not "fully-formed".  Looks like 4 identical plates/racks to scan using the same criteria, with only a 3-column shift in the output location between plates.

Comment: ...just guessing though - it looks like a lot of lab work I've done previously.

Comment: All of these worked great!  I appreciate all the help/explanations!  And Tim, your lab assumption is correct.  Trying to standardize something about covid.  Again thanks everyone!   You have no idea how much this helped!

Comment: Good luck!  We need all the help we can get.

Comment: @TimWilliams Isn't that the truth!

Answer (score 0):

Heavily commented to show what everything does.

```
Option Explicit

Sub generateRR()
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = wb.Worksheets("PATIENT INFO COPY-PASTE")
Dim dest As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim rowNum As Integer
Dim colNum As Integer

'prevent the screen from updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'n is the Rack number. Loop 4 times (4 racks)
For n = 1 To 4
    'set the destination for the data (ex: Worksheets("Rack 1")
    Set dest = wb.Worksheets("Rack " & n)
    'loop through each of the 94 samples
    For i = 1 To 94
        If i = 1 Then
            'if it is the first sample, start at column 5 (E) row 6
            rowNum = 6
            colNum = 5
        Else
            'otherwise just add to the existing column number
            colNum = colNum + 1
        End If
        If i = 11 Or i = 23 Or i = 35 Or i = 47 Or i = 59 Or i = 71 Or i = 83 Then
            'start a new line as needed
            colNum = 3
            rowNum = rowNum + 1
        End If
        'add the data from Worksheets("PATIENT INFO COPY-PASTE")
        dest.Cells(rowNum, colNum) = src.Cells(i + 1, n)
    'next iteration of samples
    Next i
'next iteration of Racks
Next n

'start seeing screen updates again
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```